# Run backgroundtask simultaneous with foreground xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, background, raspberry-pi

I am trying to integrate a background application into a foreground application which needs to run simultaneously.
                                                                                  I have been reading many Microsoft docs and it seems like I cant understand what they meant. I am a begineer at XAML.This is supposed to be for raspberry pi where the background codes are for the sensors while the foreground should have buttons where user can tap for an OTP if they dont have RFID.The OTP i can manage but i am having problem integrating background into XAML.
                                                                                I am overly stressed about this. Please help me

UPDATE:

I am going to try your suggestion on the Pi tomorrow and hopefully it will work :)

```
         private void OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {

        int interval = 20;
        DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(interval);

        while (true)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now >= dueTime)
            {
                //insert code here
                initComms();
                StartUart();

                //self monitoring 
                startLightMonitoring();

                //Initial State
                CurMode = Neutral;
                Debug.WriteLine("===Entering MODE_SENDLIGHT===");

                // This make sure the main program run idefinitely 
                while (true)
                {
                    Sleep(300);

                    //state machine
                    handleModeSendLight();

                    if (CurMode == Neutral)
                    {
                        MailBoxMonitoring();
                    }
                    else if (CurMode == AccessMode)
                    {
                        AccessGranted();
                    }
                    else if (CurMode == IntrusionMode)
                    {
                        InvalidAccess();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Config Error");
                    }
                    //Update next dueTime
                    dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(interval);
                }


            }
            else
            {
                //Just yield to not tax out the CPU
                Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The terms you are looking for are Multitasking and Multithreading. Those are the only ways to have two codes run in paralell. I only know the options inherent in hte .NET Framework myself, so I am not sure wich ones you have.

Comment: I thought Its not possible to run .NET stuff in Xaml

Comment: Well, you do not. If you use XAML, that implies you use MVVM or have some code behind. That will naturally run on the GUI thread. But you can start a extra Task or Thread from the View Model, same as any other .NET Code.

Comment: Yeap but I am not so familiar with XAML  and the code examples i been trying to understand doesnt make any sense to me https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task

Comment: I have to write a proper answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

**MVVM:**

You are using XAML and UWP. That means you should be using the MVVM pattern. While you can use other approaches, XAML and WPF/UWP were designed with MVVM in mind. You loose about 90% of the power of XAML and run into loads of additonal issues by not using MVVM. I wrote a intro into it years back:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

**Background Operations:**

There are many ways to do Multitasking/-Threading in .NET. BackgroundWorker, Async...await, Tasks, Threads an what you linked in the comments above. For beginners I would advise the background worker and I wrote a example code for this. But your case is not precisely beginner level:

```html
#region Primenumbers
private void btnPrimStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!bgwPrim.IsBusy)
 {
  //Prepare ProgressBar and Textbox
  int temp = (int)nudPrim.Value;
  pgbPrim.Maximum = temp;
  tbPrim.Text = "";

  //Start processing
  bgwPrim.RunWorkerAsync(temp);
 }
}

private void btnPrimCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (bgwPrim.IsBusy)
 {
  bgwPrim.CancelAsync();
 }
}

private void bgwPrim_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
 int highestToCheck = (int)e.Argument;
 //Get a reference to the BackgroundWorker running this code
 //for Progress Updates and Cancelation checking
 BackgroundWorker thisWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

 //Create the list that stores the results and is returned by DoWork
 List<int> Primes = new List<int>();
 

 //Check all uneven numbers between 1 and whatever the user choose as upper limit
 for(int PrimeCandidate=1; PrimeCandidate < highestToCheck; PrimeCandidate+=2)
 {
  //Report progress
  thisWorker.ReportProgress(PrimeCandidate);
  bool isNoPrime = false;

  //Check if the Cancelation was requested during the last loop
  if (thisWorker.CancellationPending)
  {
   //Tell the Backgroundworker you are canceling and exit the for-loop
   e.Cancel = true;
   break;
  }

  //Determin if this is a Prime Number
  for (int j = 3; j < PrimeCandidate && !isNoPrime; j += 2)
  {
   if (PrimeCandidate % j == 0)
    isNoPrime = true;
  }

  if (!isNoPrime)
   Primes.Add(PrimeCandidate);
 }

 //Tell the progress bar you are finished
 thisWorker.ReportProgress(highestToCheck);

 //Save Return Value
 e.Result = Primes.ToArray();
}

private void bgwPrim_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
 pgbPrim.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void bgwPrim_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
 pgbPrim.Value = pgbPrim.Maximum;
 this.Refresh();

 if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
 {
  //Show the Result
  int[] Primes = (int[])e.Result;

  StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (int Prim in Primes)
  {
   sbOutput.Append(Prim.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
  }

  tbPrim.Text = sbOutput.ToString();
 }
 else 
 {
  tbPrim.Text = "Operation canceled by user or Exception";
 }
}
#endregion
```

You could use progress report to deliver the current sensor data out of the Thread. Expose them in a Property on the ViewModel.

**GUI Write overhead:**

Your case is tricky, because you need a thread that pretty much runs permanently and does most work via Progress Reporting. The thing is that writing the GUI is quite costly. That does not mater if you only do it once per user started event, but here you have a loop (in the other Thread or Task) doing repeated writing (via change notification or directly). You can totally overload the GUI thread with too many changes. Indeed my original variant of above code did just that: I tried to hand out each found prime via Progress reporting and then append it to the output box. At a large enough upper bound it found so many primes so quickly, that string appending them to the output box fully taxed out the GUI thread for a while. As primes became rare, the GUI thread managed to catch up. But you data gathering will always work on the same speed. I wrote an example for this issues too:

```html
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UIWriteOverhead
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int[] getNumbers(int upperLimit)
        {
            int[] ReturnValue = new int[upperLimit];

            for (int i = 0; i < ReturnValue.Length; i++)
                ReturnValue[i] = i;

            return ReturnValue;
        }

        void printWithBuffer(int[] Values)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            string buffer = "";

            foreach (int Number in Values)
                buffer += Number.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            textBox1.Text = buffer;
        }

        void printDirectly(int[] Values){
            textBox1.Text = "";

            foreach (int Number in Values)
                textBox1.Text += Number.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        private void btnPrintBuffer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Generating Numbers");
            int[] temp = getNumbers(10000);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing with buffer");
            printWithBuffer(temp);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing done");
        }

        private void btnPrintDirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Generating Numbers");
            int[] temp = getNumbers(1000);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing directly");
            printDirectly(temp);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing done");
        }
    }
}
```

There are two ways around that:

1. Do not use change notification. You can still use a property that is equiped for it on the ViewModel side, but do not let the View Register it. Instead let the view poll the values via a Timer. That way you can keep the changes of the GUI to a manageable level.
2. Limit how often new data is gathered. You can apply simple rate limiting so new data is not aquired (and Reported) too often:

   ```html
   integer interval = 20;
   DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(interval);

   while(true){
     if(DateTime.Now >= dueTime){
       //insert code here

    //Update next dueTime
    dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(interval);
     }
     else{
       //Just yield to not tax out the CPU
       Thread.Sleep(1);
     }
   }
   ```

   Note that this is only a upper bound. If data gathering takes 20 milliseconds each itteartion, this code will not run faster. Also the Windows Clock used by DateTime.Now is not nearly as [accurate as the Type allows Precision](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime/). In tests I had delays of 5-18 ms and those values kept changing.

Comment: Basically what you mean is that instead of running the background code without stopping, I should run my sensor codes in interval of milliseconds?

Comment: Personall I would rather limit how often the GUI updates, then how often the data is gathered. That allows you to reuse the same ViewModel in a View that can process changes faster (possibly even as fast as the data comes in) - including the same programm running on a Desktop/Laptop rather then a Mobile Phone.